# Spyne: array of 1 or more integers

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, spyne

I have this service:

```
class CategoryService(ServiceBase):

    @rpc(Array(Integer(min_occurs=1, max_occurs='unbounded', nillable=False), **MANDATORY),
         _returns=Iterable(Category, **MANDATORY))
    def get_subcategories_by_path(ctx, category_path):
        ...
```

This is shown in WSDL as:

```
<xs:complexType name="get_subcategories_by_path">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="category_path" type="tns:integerArray"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="integerArray">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="integer" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I want `category_path` argument to be an array of 1 or more integers, but `Array(Integer(min_occurs=1, max_occurs='unbounded', nillable=False)` does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` is for wrapped array types. To get simple ones, you should use the type markers  directly. The following should do the trick:

```
class CategoryService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Integer(min_occurs=1, max_occurs='unbounded', nillable=False)),
                                        _returns=Iterable(Category, **MANDATORY))
    def get_subcategories_by_path(ctx, category_path):
        # (...)
```

Comment: Does this mean that `@rpc(Mandatory.Unicode, Array(Unicode, default='*'), Array(Unicode), Array(Unicode), Array(Unicode), _returns=ProductWithRelations) def get_product_by_sku(            ctx, product_sku, include_columns, exclude_columns,            include_relationships, exclude_relationships):` can be safely rewritten as `@rpc(Mandatory.Unicode, Unicode(max_occurs='unbounded', default='*'), Unicode(max_occurs='unbounded'), Unicode(max_occurs='unbounded'), Unicode(max_occurs='unbounded'), _returns=ProductWithRelations)`?

Comment: uh, no, you have 4 arrays in the first and one array in the second. Also, the wsdl produced by Array(...) and Unicode(max_occurs='unbounded') is different.

Comment: but looks like the second form is fine: `<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="product_sku" type="tns:MandatoryString"/>
<xs:element name="include_columns" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:element name="exclude_columns" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:element name="include_relationships" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:element name="exclude_relationships" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>`

Comment: Well, if it looks fine, nothing will change in the python side. Both will deserialize as arrays of designated types.